# How to measure distance using ARCore?

Tags: java, android, augmented-reality, arcore

Is it possible to calculate distance between two `HitResult` `s ?

Or how we can calculate real distance (e.g. meters) using ARCore?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

In Java ARCore world units are meters (I just realized we might not document this... aaaand looks like nope.  *Oops*, bug filed).  By subtracting the translation component of two `Pose`s you can get the distance between them.  Your code would look something like this:

On first hit as `hitResult`:

```
startAnchor = session.addAnchor(hitResult.getHitPose());
```

On second hit as `hitResult`:

```
Pose startPose = startAnchor.getPose();
Pose endPose = hitResult.getHitPose();

// Clean up the anchor
session.removeAnchors(Collections.singleton(startAnchor));
startAnchor = null;

// Compute the difference vector between the two hit locations.
float dx = startPose.tx() - endPose.tx();
float dy = startPose.ty() - endPose.ty();
float dz = startPose.tz() - endPose.tz();

// Compute the straight-line distance.
float distanceMeters = (float) Math.sqrt(dx*dx + dy*dy + dz*dz);
```

Assuming that these hit results don't happen on the same frame, creating an `Anchor` is important because the virtual world can be reshaped every time you call `Session.update()`.  By holding that location with an anchor instead of just a Pose, its Pose will update to track the physical feature across those reshapings.

Comment: ``ARCore world units are meters `` - Awesome! Is this also valid for Unity?

Comment: Just confirmed that yes, meters in Unity too.  Unreal might be cm or something.

Answer (score 6):

**The answer is: Yes**, you definitely can calculate distance between two `HitResult`'s. The working units of `ARCore`, as well as `ARKit`, are `meters`. Sometimes, it's more useful to use `centimetres`. Here are a few ways how you do it with Java and great old `Pythagorean theorem`.

[image]

```
import com.google.ar.core.HitResult

MotionEvent tap = queuedSingleTaps.poll();
if (tap != null && camera.getTrackingState() == TrackingState.TRACKING) {
    for (HitResult hit : frame.hitTest(tap)) {
        // some logic...
    }
}

// Here's the principle how you can calculate the distance  
// between two anchors in 3D space using Java:

private double getDistanceMeters(Pose pose0, Pose pose1) {

    float distanceX = pose0.tx() - pose1.tx();
    float distanceY = pose0.ty() - pose1.ty();
    float distanceZ = pose0.tz() - pose1.tz();

    return Math.sqrt(distanceX * distanceX + 
                     distanceY * distanceY + 
                     distanceZ * distanceZ);
} 
 
// Convert Meters into Centimetres

double distanceCm = ((int)(getDistanceMeters(pose0, pose1) * 1000))/10.0f;

// pose0 is the location of first Anchor
// pose1 is the location of second Anchor
```

Alternatively, you can use the following math:

```
Pose pose0 = firstAnchor.getPose()     // first pose
Pose pose1 = secondAnchor.getPose()    // second pose

double distanceM = Math.sqrt(Math.pow((pose0.tx() - pose1.tx()), 2) + 
                             Math.pow((pose0.ty() - pose1.ty()), 2) +
                             Math.pow((pose0.tz() - pose1.tz()), 2));

double distanceCm = ((int)(distanceM * 1000))/10.0f;
```

Comment: Can you please share your full code? It would help me a lot

Comment: Can you please help me with getting the `height` of the object. Suppose I have placed a cube at some point and scaling that cube. Now the final value which is coming is in vectors. I don'y have any reference to convert that into meters.

Comment: Why are you multiplying by 100 (1000/10=100) to convert meters to centimeters?  Why not just do distanceInMeters*100?

Comment: Because distanceM typecasted to `int` but result is divided by `float`. Although, you can calculate it the way you like))) It's a precision issue...

Answer (score 5):

You can extract the two `HitResult` poses using [getHitPose()](https://developers.google.com/ar/reference/java/com/google/ar/core/HitResult.html#getHitPose()) and then compare their translation component ([getTranslation()](https://developers.google.com/ar/reference/java/com/google/ar/core/Pose.html#getTranslation(float[],%20int))). 
The translation is defined as

> ...the position vector from the destination (usually
>   world) coordinate frame to the local coordinate frame, expressed in
>   destination (world) coordinates.

As for the physical unit of this I could not find any remark. With a calibrated camera this should be mathematically possible but I don't know if they actually provide an API for this