# ARCore scale estimation precision

Tags: android, scale, precision, estimation, arcore

According to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45982196/how-to-measure-distance-using-arcore) ARCore works in meter. But, since a single camera can't be used to guess the size of what is viewed -This is a known phenomenon for monocular SLAM which also can lead to scale drift, which the TANGO devices avoided by using a RGB-D camera- it probably relies on the IMU to guess the real size of what is viewed by the camera. Yet, I don't expect the IMU of common smartphone to give very precise estimation of motion. So, what level of fidelity and precision can expect we expect of ARCore regarding scale estimation and scale drift? Moreover is there certain conditions that are known to give poor result?

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear what range of distance you are wondering about, but you can try out Google's Measure app which lets you use a virtual tape measure to check real-life measurements using ARCore. It was able to measure a 5.5 by 7.5 foot rug within a couple of inches. Give it a try!

Measure app:
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.tango.measure