# Where and how do I implement getDistance() between two points in the HelloArActivity v1.1.0?

Tags: java, android-studio, arcore

[How to measure distance using ARCore?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45982196/how-to-measure-distance-using-arcore)

I have seen this thread and still don't understand how or where to use the sample of code.

Answer (score 0):

I answered my own question buy doing this in the onDrawFrame() method

```
        anchors.add(hit.createAnchor());

          Pose pose1 = hit.getHitPose();
          Pose pose2 = hit.getHitPose();
          pose1 = anchors.get(0).getPose();
          pose2 = anchors.get(1).getPose();
          double distance = getDistance(pose1, pose2);
          String result = String.valueOf(distance);
          showResult(result);
```