# Given 2 pixels, how can I compute the real distance with ARCore?

Tags: arcore

Given an image (frame) I would like to have a function that takes 2 pixels as an argument and then returns the real world distance between those pixels. Is this possible with ARCore? Note that the image is just a random frame of a series of frames, so that initializing measurement should work.
What could I look into for this?

Comment: Is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45982196/how-to-measure-distance-using-arcore) what you want? If not, how is it different?

Comment: I'm pretty new to this, but as far as I understand that, I cannot set an anchor to an arbitrary pixel right?